# Where does the "spring-context.xml" file go in a WebApp context?

Tags: java, spring, classpath, vaadin

In short: I don't know which folder to place the "spring-context.xml" file in a WebApp when I'm doing this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
```

In Long: I know what a classpath is basically.  It used to be an environment variable that told the Java project where to look for jars and other resources.  It doesn't seem to be used much.  But in Eclipse, it talks about setting your classpath by going into your Java Build Path.

What I don't understand it when I want to find a Spring "spring-context.xml" file using the classpath (above) what that has to do with the Eclipse Java Build Path, if anything!  What folders does a WebApp look in when I use the above statement?  I usually hear people say, "In the classpath" but that doesn't tell me much since I don't want to use an environment variable and the Eclipse Java Build Path seems to have little to do with finding the spring-context.xml file.

**More Detail**

Initially I was afraid that more details would confuse the situation, but maybe they hold a key.

I am using Vaadin to create a web app.  I'm following their direction for how to get a Spring context into Vaadin.  I've created a Spring Helper class:

```
public SpringContextHelper(Application application) {
    ServletContext servletContext = ((WebApplicationContext) application.getContext()).getHttpSession().getServletContext();
    context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
}
```

In the `web.xml` I have these sections:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'm getting the error in the first line of `SpringContextHelper()`.  I've broken the line down so I know it is this logic that is failing:

```
WebApplicationContext wac = (WebApplicationContext) application.getContext();
```

`wac` comes back null, presumably because is can't find the `spring-context.xml` file.

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to be used much"*: this is a huge misconception. *"But in Eclipse, it talks about setting your classpath by going into your Java Build Path."*: not necessarily, some paths are by default already covered by the classpath, such as `src` folder, `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`, `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`, etc. So whatever you drop there, it will "automagically" end up in webapp's runtime classpath (that's among others what an IDE is good for; so that you don't need to fiddle with `javac -cp` everytime and so on).

Comment: So "src", "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib", and "WebContent/WEB-INF/classes".  How do I know what "WebContent" is?  I thought it was "webapp".  And what other paths are built in?

Comment: I am talking in Eclipse's perspective. "WebContent" is the default name of public web content folder of a dynamic web project. Other paths are among others `Server/lib`, `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext`, etc. You can find them all out during runtime by `ClassLoader#getResources()`.

Comment: `ClassLoader#getResources()` seems to need a name and my problem is I don't know where to put `spring-context.xml`.  If I use that as the name, I get nothing back.  On another note, where would I find the name of the public web content folder of a dynamic web project?

Comment: As an use example, use `classLoader.getResources("")`. As to the XML file not being found, just put it in one of the default paths covered by the webapp's runtime classpath, or add its path to the webapp's runtime classpath.

Comment: @BalusC: `classLoader.getResources("")` returns null.  I've put `spring-context.xml` in all the "standard" folders I can think of and it doesn't find it.  I think I'll edit the question and put more details in it, as it seems the environment is not as one would except it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the "Java Build path" you specify for a project *is* the CLASSPATH.

And files you put in the "src" root of your "Java Resources" project folder will automatically go in your web app's "classes" subdirectory (i.e will automatically be available as in the runtime CLASSPATH).

For example, if you have a custom log4j.properties file, then it can and should go in your Eclipse project's "src/" root.

As far as "where does spring-context.xml go?", I don't know.  This link suggests it should go under META-INF/jsca (at least for WebLogic):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15315_09/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.doc/html/sca.html

Comment: My problem is that I can't put my `spring-context.xml` file in a folder that the statement above in the question will find.  I get an error at runtime.  Putting `spring-context.xml` in `src` still gets a runtime error.

Comment: Suggestion: Do a "File, Export as .war" from your Eclipse project.  Look at the .war file (there are several ways to do this, including renaming from .war to .zip and looking at the contents with Windows Explorer).  That will help show you how your Eclipse project files and directories map to Tomcat/App server runtime files and directories.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm5: The exception is `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException`.  This happens on this line: `HttpSession hs = wac.getHttpSession();`.  `wac` comes from this: `WebApplicationContext wac = (WebApplicationContext) application.getContext();`.  So my assumption is that it can't find the spring-context.xml file.

Comment: @paulsm5: `spring-context.xml` is in `WEB-INF/classes` in the war file.  What does that mean as to where I should put `spring-context.xml` in the Eclipse project?